# Install Windows 7 on Asus Eee pc 1011px netbook

Tags: windows-7, netbook, eee-pc

I have a  [Asus Eee pc 1011px netbook](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/Eee_PC_1011PX/specifications/) which it had  an original windows 7 starter installed on it ! 
It had 16 GB partition for windows recovery ! 
it was working well,  until I wnated to install  ubuntu next to windows ! so I tried to separate 10 GB to install Ubuntu 
I did it by Windows "Disk management" and after that i tried to "create a new partition"  but  the created partition  was the recovery partition !

after restart  when I wnat to boot with windows 7 it says : "Press Alt + Ctl + del " to restart ! in a black page !

when I boot system with a live ubuntu I see that the windows partion have not changed at all ! 
anyway I tried to install new windows 7 !  so I created  an .ISO file from an windos disk (that im sure that works good ) and by RUFUS software i created an bootable usb and I boot system and tried to instal windows   but when I want to select partition to install windows , it says :

" No drivers were found.Clic Load Driver to Provide a mass storage driver for installation "

For a week I searched many manners for this problem and i download  many drivers from [asus support](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/Eee_PC_1011PX/HelpDesk_Download/)
but Problem is still remaning ! 
please help me  and give me sure answer

Comment: Do you have your Windows product key? The product key for my Asus Zenbook is printed on the power supply.

Comment: Was it able to load the storage driver and identify the drive to install to once loaded?

Comment: @PFitz under the notbook there is a pruduct key , but Im not sure is that windows pruduct key or not ! what shal i do if it is ?

Comment: @Optichip what do you mean of "storage" ? It identify the usb flash and runs windows setup , but does not identify  hard disc

Comment: @SoheilYou If you go through the installation of Windows 7 and you get to the part where it asks you what drive to install on, no drive is listed but you have the option to install a driver, at that point, you put in the USB stick that has the driver on it that you want to use, select it, the driver loads, then you put your Windows 7 usb stick back in and complete the install.  This is the driver I'm referring to.

Comment: @Optichip yes ! when i click on "load driver" in identify usb flash an files ! but I dont know what drivers ?  could you send me a link to download it? I have serched for a week but all drivers are wrong ! I dont know which driver shal I install

Comment: @SoheilYou http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/Eee_PC_1011PX/HelpDesk_Download/  Please go to the manufacturer site and select SATA and download that driver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20241/discussion-between-soheilyou-and-optichip).

Comment: All `Windows 7` OEM devices are required to have a COA which indicate the version of the version of `Windows 7` installed and the license key.  This is universal requirement by Microsoft in order to sell `Windows 7` devices.

Comment: @Ramhound I want to update my bios and install windows from a usb , can i do that?

Comment: I have no idea.  I am just responding to the fact.  You are not sure if the number you found was a license key or not.   You should locate the COA on the device.

Comment: @Ramhound Now Im sure thats it ! what shall I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could fix it :) ! 
I'll say my manner for other  people who have this problem ! 
after a lot of efforts finally I booted my netbook by a Ubuntu 11.10 live USB and I installed ubuntu  in  withot seetiing partitions manualy , and ubuntu erased my hard disk compeeltly and after that i booted my  netbook by windows 7 usb and after that windows setup was able to identify my hard and installed windows 7 successfully ! 
realy tnx for dear @Optichip :)